# Uninstalling standard plugins on Eclipse Juno (4.2)

Tags: eclipse

In case someone else want's to get rid of some plugins which are part of the default Eclipse bundles:

Removing Mylyn, M2Eclipse and EGit was not possible via "Eclipse Installation Details -> Uninstall". The uninstall button is disabled for all plugins. Perhaps "standard" plugins pre-bundled in the download bundle from eclipse.org cannot be removed via the UI.

If someone knows how it should be correctly done please share.

Answer (score 1):

I Removed the corresponding plugins and features on the filesystem directly which did not break the installation (at least in my case). Directories can be easily identified by their package names.

If someone knows how it should be correctly done please share.

Comment: dont try this, in my case eclipse was working but I have lot of problems

Comment: What problems exactly ?

Comment: I removed the google (unofficial) protobuf plugin. My eclipse starts but I cant compile and edit files (it throws me errors)

Comment: ok. I'm not sure where the protobuf plugin comes from and where it's used but I think it the plugins I removed are kind of official (optional) plugins anyway and it's now a couple of weeks since I tossed the plugins from the disk (Mylyn, M2Eclipse and EGit) and there were 0 issues in my case. Would love to see a way to get a trimmed down standard bundle from Eclipse.org without going through the Yoxos hassle.